# What is the correct syntax / format for entering information into the struct vector shown below

Tags: c++

I am new to programming, and am trying to figure out one thing at a time.
What is the correct format for inputting information into the vector in line 13?
I am getting an error of StudentInformation has no member studentNames.

```
1   struct StudentInformation
2   {
3   std::string studentNames{};
4   int studentScores{};
5   };
6   
7   void getInformation( int numberOfStudents, std::vector < StudentInformation> student )
8   {
9   for (int enterNameItterate{ 0 }; enterNameItterate = numberOfStudents; ++enterNameItterate)
10      {
11          std::cout << "Enter the name of the next student:  ";
12          std::string studentName;
13          std::cin >> student.studentNames[enterNameItterate]{ studentName };
14              std::cout << "Enter the score of student: " <<                          student.studentNames[enterNameItterate]{ studentName } <<               ":  ";
15              int studentScore;
16              std::cin >> student.studentScores[enterNameItterate]{ studentScore };
17      }
18  }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I would recommend reading up on [vectors](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/vector-in-cpp-stl/). A vector, to put it simply, is a collection of objects (in this case `StudentInformation`). You will have to select an object by it's index *before* you reference a property of that object. So for your example, you would change `student.studentNames[enterNameItterate]` to `student[enterNameItterate].studentNames`. Also put a `=` [(simple assignment operator)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_assignment) before the first curly bracket on that same line.

Answer (score 0):

You just want

```
std::cin >> student[enterNameItterate].studentNames;
```

If you dumb it down to just

```
std::string s;
std::cin >> s;
```

It might make it more obvious. The above code assumes you've already allocated the space for your `vector`, otherwise you would want this instead:

```
std::string studentName;
std::cin >> studentName;
int score = 0;
std::cin >> score;
student.emplace_back({studentName, score});
```

Something else that will quickly bite you on the bum: you're passing your `vector` into `getInformation` as a *copy* which means when you alter it within the function, you're not altering the actual object, but a copy of it. You can solve this by *returning* the vector of inputted information, or taking the `vector` by reference. Either:

```
std::vector<StudentInformation> getInformation(int numberOfStudents);
OR
void getInformation(int numberOfStudents, std::vector<StudentInformation>& student); // notice the &
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change your structure slightly to provide a handy constructor function that takes a name and a score, e.g.

```cpp
struct StudentInformation
{
    StudentInformation() = default;
    StudentInformation(const std::string& name, int score)
      : name(name), score(score) {}

    // renamed vars to something nicer.
    std::string name{};
    int score{};
};
```

I would change your function arguments slightly, so that you take a *reference* to an array of students. *(Notice the '&' in the argument?)*

```cpp
void getInformation( int numberOfStudents, std::vector<StudentInformation>& students )
{
  // simplifying the naming here. 'i' is generally known to be a counter.
  for (int i = 0; i = numberOfStudents; ++i)
  {
    // some temp vars to store entered fields
    std::string studentName;
    int studentScore;

    // get the data from the user
    std::cout << "Enter the name of the next student:  ";
    std::cin >> studentName;
    std::cout << "Enter the score of student: " << studentName << ":  ";
    std::cin >> studentScore;

    // construct a new object at the end of the vector. 
    // this will call the constructor that takes two args
    students.emplace_back(studentName, studentScore);
  }
}
```